I am getting error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createAllDayEvent')
My script is working, but is getting this error everytime and I couldn't find the root cause for it. I'm new here and would appreciate if someone could point out my mistake.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createAllDayEvent')
Script Janeiro.gs:12
function month01(){
  // get Calendar ID
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  let id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("CalendarID").getValue()
  
  // get Event data...the filter allows us to only get rows that contain data, and to exclude the checkbox in the filter
  let events = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("EventList01").getValues().filter(array => array.slice(0, -1).some(value => value !== ''));

  //single day event with just title and date
  events.forEach( function(e, index){
    if(!e[22]){
      CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id).createAllDayEvent(
        e[2],
        e[0],
        {description: e[1]})
      let newIndex = index+3;
      sheet.getRange("AB"+ newIndex).setValue(true)
    }
  })
}

Thanks for helping!

It looks like  your calendar id must be incorrect

And you can not really set a cell equal to a boolean unless you are using it in the sense of truthiness or falsiness.  So if you are trying  to set a checkbox to checked then try sheet.getRange("AB" + row).setValue("TRUE")
